# Segmentation fault due to lack of memory in C

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, memory-management, segmentation-fault

This code gives me segmentation fault about 1/2 of the time:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    float test[2619560];
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 2619560; i++)
        test[i] = 1.0f;
}
```

I actually need to allocate a much larger array, is there some way of allowing the operating system to allow me get more memory?

I am using Linux Ubuntu 9.10

Answer (score 25):

You are overflowing the default maximum stack size, which is 8 MB.

You can either increase the stack size - eg. for 32 MB:

```
ulimit -s 32767
```

... or you can switch to allocation with `malloc`:

```
float *test = malloc(2619560 * sizeof test[0]);
```

Comment: If you use malloc, you're able to check in the code if the allocation was successful - much better than running through the allocation and hoping it doesn't crash.  (addendum, not so much a comment @caf)

Comment: @Sam Dufel Be aware that some systems (e.g. linux by default) can return you a non-null pointer from malloc even if you're out of memory - leading to similar crashes when you try to access that memory.

Comment: It's probably more accurate to say that some systems separate the notions of allocating virtual address space and committing backing store.

Comment: According to the malloc man page, 'The Unix98 standard requires malloc(), calloc(), and realloc() to set errno  to ENOMEM upon failure. Glibc assumes that this is done (and the glibc versions of these routines do this); if you use a private malloc implementation that does not set errno, then certain library routines may fail without having a reason in errno.'

Answer (score 7):

Right now you're allocating (or at least trying to) `2619560*sizeof(float)` bytes on the stack. At least in most typical cases, the stack can use only a limited amount of memory. You might try defining it `static` instead:

```
static float test[2619560];
```

This gets it out of the stack, so it can typically use any available memory instead. In other functions, defining something as `static` changes the semantics, but in the case of `main` it makes little difference (other than the mostly theoretical possibility of a recursive `main`).

Comment: Recursive `main`, eh? Sounds interesting.

Comment: @You: Sometimes used in the IOCCC or code golf. Otherwise, not so much (and not allowed in C++).

Answer (score 1):

Don't put such a large object on the stack. Instead, consider storing it in the heap, by allocation with malloc() or its friends.

2.6M floats isn't that many, and even on a 32-bit system you should be ok for address space.

If you need to allocate a very large array, be sure to use a 64-bit system (assuming you have enough memory!). 32-bit systems can only address about 3G per process, and even then you can't allocate it all as a single contigous block.

Answer (score 0):

It is the stack overflower.
You'd better to use malloc function to get memory larger than stack size which you can get it from "ulimit -s".